# How to set a splash screen to last as long as my database loads?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I am still relatively new to Android. I followed this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) on Architecture Components to store around 2k objects in my database from a server.

I implemented my splash screen using a `layer-list` ([source](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)) which entails that the splash screen will last as long as the MainActivity has some processing to do. Since the DB is loaded on the back thread, it avoids this condition.

That causes my application to start without the data that takes a roughly 10 more seconds to load on startup while everything is pretty much freezed. Once it loads, everything works fine but I get hit with this obvious message from the Choreographer:
`I/Choreographer: Skipped 1208 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

So my question is, to avoid skipping all these frames and for my app to not lag, how do I implement my `SplashActivity` (or `MainActivity`??) so that my `MainActivity` does not start before all my data has been loaded???

Comment: You can use a callback, event bus, or observer, to start the new intent when the database is done.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai What a simple sentence can do. Fixed my problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

load your database asynchorously (I suggest using coroutine) and then start your activity when finished